# Regex or parsing that only gets domain and ignores everything else

Tags: regex, parsing

I'm having a bit of a rough time here. I have searched a lot here on stack overflow and there are some solutions that claim to do this but none that meet my need. Looking at my attempts so far I am not clear why they don't work. Here they are:

```
[^A-Za-z]{3,9}(?:\/\/){0,1}(?:www\.)?(.+)(?:[\/:?])

(?:https?\:\/\/)(?:www.?)([^\/:?#]+)(?:[\/:?#]|$)

(?::\/\/?)(?:www\.?)(.[^\/:?]+)
```

I need to just get the base domain. The issue with these is they fail to match one case I really also need to be able to match. The case where all I have is a domain. Test data:

```
http://www.bing.com/search?q=hola
http://www.bing.com/
http://www.bing.com:80/
http://www.bing.com:80
bing.com:80
bing.com
a@gmail.com
Flappy Bird
127.4.4.4
140BBAA7-2654-4424-9C7C-6828ECBDA177
```

I should have six matches. All saying bing.com. However, the last two bing entries in my test data simply do not match. Any pointers here? Honestly doesn't even need to be regex but I also need to ensure its a domain specifically so I figured this would be the better solution. Thank you.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark: [`https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?[^.\/]*(?:\.[^.:\/\n]+)+|^[^.@\n]+\.[^\d.:\n@]+`](https://regex101.com/r/iH1nK6/1).

Comment: Well, this will extract bing.com from the six (with Perl regexes; you didn't give the regex convention you're using): `([^:/.]+\.[^:/.]+)(?:$|[:?/])` But you need to provide more information on what should match and what shouldn't. E.g. for what reason should `127.4.4.4` fail to match?

Comment: Why is `gmail.com` not supposed to be a match in your test data?

Comment: Its an email address. I don't want email addresses.

Comment: @Gene this is scala so in the end it should be Java conventions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in Perl syntax this extracts all the `bing.com`s and rejects all but one of the malformed examples:

```
^(?:http:\/\/)?(?:[^:/.@]+\.)*([^:/.@]+\.[^:/.]+)(?:$|[:?/])
```

It does match `127.4.4.4` and extracts `4.4`. To fix that, you are going to have to tell us *why* that's an incorrect answer. You may want to explicitly match a quad of octets with a separate regex:

```
^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$
```

and deal with that as an error in separate code.

If either regex doesn't work in your engine, you will also have to tell us which you're using. Regex syntax is far from universal.

Comment: Because my product people say so like most things. I think in this case an IP is valid but for this purpose they do not feel it is. I still need bing.com as it is considered a valid input. Extracting 4.4 and the guid would be considered bad input. I can't really get in to the details but these are the requirements and I figured this would be better than writing a parser for arbitrary rules then validating it but I might be wrong.

Comment: ^(?:http:\/\/)?(?:[^:\/.@]+\.)?([^:\/.@]+\.[^:\/.]+)(?:$|[:?\/]) seems to do what I want